# AngularJS 2 - Reuse Components

Tags: angular

I am using `AngularJS` as templating FrameWork in my project.

I don't want to use **only** `Angular`, but also insert some `HTML`.

Ex from [Angular Tutorial](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qax2k4Yt0aqtD7DXyjmz?p=preview):

```html
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <hr />
    <!-- Another selector but doesn't work -->
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

I want to reuse the selector but the second call is not replaced by the template.

Is there any way to reuse a component while inserting different data between calls?

I know how `Angular2` works with the global component and the childs but is there any way to bypass it?
Like using partials components?

I know it can be done like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/0R56LCeI2j2S9wTSV9fe?p=preview).

However, if i want to reuse the template 3 times while inserting different data, i have to declare 3 components?
Is it possible to create many instances of the same selector ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. Both times the first tag is addressed, the 2nd isn't reached. You'd need something like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/915

and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7136
which demonstrates a workaround http://plnkr.co/edit/O0KRZHUz5jdW40mY1EgA?p=preview.

```ts
let app = platform(BROWSER_PROVIDERS).application([BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS]);

function bootstrapWithCustomSelector(app, componentType, selector:string) {
  var bootstrapProviders = [
      provide(APP_COMPONENT_REF_PROMISE,
              {
                useFactory: (dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, appRef: ApplicationRef,
                             injector: Injector) => {
                  console.log('now');   
                  var ref: ComponentRef;
                  return dynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot(componentType, selector, injector,
                                                           () => { appRef._unloadComponent(ref); })
                      .then((componentRef) => ref = componentRef );
                },
                deps: [DynamicComponentLoader, ApplicationRef, Injector]
              }),

  ];  
  return app.bootstrap(componentType, bootstrapProviders);
}

bootstrapWithCustomSelector(app, AppComponent, 'my-custom-app');
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the workaround only allows to rename the selector but I can't reuse it. I still can't add another instance of the selector "my-custom-app".
Or, is there any practical way to use this workaround for what I want to do ?

Comment: Seems to be the other way around tha what you want. The workaround allows to bootstrap the same component twice.

Comment: I tried to use this workaround to somewhat reach the needed result.
I use Input to allow the provider to return different data.
I have a problem with the view : http://plnkr.co/edit/cDrAL84k1BKMKzEG7jU6?p=preview

Comment: I haven't used it myself. I just remembered seeing the discussion in GitHub. I guess the problem is caused by `loadAsRoot` which is currently broken.